# How to make JUnit tests print output only for failed test cases?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, continuous-integration

We have a lot of tests running as part of our CI, and tests do print a lot of text output to stdout/err.

The output is becoming too large (~20 MB in size) to be viewed on the UI, and the team now has to download it to their system and open it.

[image]

We use maven and junit is the test runner. Can I somehow configure `mvn test` to print the stdout only for test case failures?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-logging -> `mvn test -q`

Comment: @TimothyTruckle This will not completely suppress the output from passing test cases. If 1000 tests ran and 1001th test failed, I want only the 1001th test's stdout/err to be present in the log.

Comment: Why do your tests have so much output anyway? A passing test should never have to print anything anyway and a failing test should tell you what failed by itself, without looking at additionl output.

Comment: @EricSchaefer Badly written tests, unfortunately. :/

But also the classes under test has a lot of log lines. We test negative paths which would print stack traces. They all together makes the output very verbose.